# Bootstrap card double clickable area - Angular 5

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a Bootstrap `card` which is able to call to two of my methods.

```
<div (click)="TEST1()" class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <button (click)="(TEST2)">TEST2BUTTON</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Nevertheless, and actually, it makes sense, where I click it will always call to `TEST1()`. Is there any way to call `TEST2()` when clicking on the `button`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) inside your event callback.

Change your template to this, notice the `$event` parameter being passed:

```
 <button (click)="onClick2($event)">TEST2BUTTON</button>
```

and in your component:

```
onClick2(event: MouseEvent): void {
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```